# Bubbles in toilet, gurgling sound coming from kitchen sink

Tags: toilet, sink

So, all of a sudden, I have big bubbles coming out from my toilet bowl when the washing machine is pushing water out. Thinking it might be a clogged toilet bowl, I took the plunger to the bowl. I flushed, and the kitchen sink started making gurgling sound.

What's going on?

Comment: It is most likely a blocked vent, not a stopped toilet. Nothing was done anywhere in the house to coincide with this problem? On the outside? It also matters where the toilet is in respect to the washing machine the sink and the vent to the outside air, which is typically on the roof

Comment: Possible duplicate: [What could cause bubbling toilet when the shower or sink is running?](http://diy.stackexchange.com/q/13321/2196)

Comment: No, nothing was done on the inside / outside of the house. Standing on the hallway, the washing machine is on the west side of the hallway; bathroom and kitchen is on the east side. As far as I can tell the flow is pretty much the same; it's not slowing down or anything. As for the vent, I couldn't possibly check it. It is probably covered in snow with today's snow storm.

Comment: Your vent may be blocked by snow/ice.

Answer (score 4):

I know a house that has this all the time because there is no vent stack. Any excess gas in the drain lines bubbles through the sinks. It's possible the snow has effectively blocked the vent pipe on the roof, causing this bubbling.

Answer (score 1):

It can also be a blocked sewer line.  I had bubbling toilets and drains and it was fixed by the sewer line being cleared out.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all for answering.

I think the problem may have been fixed. At least, that's what I'm hoping and praying for. My dad came to my house and heard the noise, went through all the bathrooms. One of the bathrooms on the north side of the house is never used because it's always very cold that part of the house. The toilet bowl was all dried up, so he flushed the toilet and there's now some water in the bowl. He also turned on the bath tub and sink faucets and let it run for a couple of minutes.
I haven't heard the noise from anywhere since then - granted I haven't done any laundry yet. But at least, the noises coming from the kitchen is gone.